# Retrieving python-pptx version

Tags: python-pptx

My code (md2pptx) uses python-pptx. I would like it to display the python-pptx version.

Is there a practical way of doing that?

My reading of the docs suggests there isn't.

Comment: As nobody has answered I'm going to open it as an issue on python-pptx - having checked if there's already one open.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @scanny for the following answer - the first of which I successfully used.

> One of these should do the trick:

```
from pptx import __version__ as pptx_version
print(pptx_version)

import pptx
print(pptx.__version__)
```